# Does an optically encoded dc motor count as a servo?

Tags: servo

Up until now, i have thought that a servo referred to a very specific type of motor: [one like this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/10pcs-x-9G-SG90-Mini-Micro-Servo-For-RC-Robot-Helicopter-Airplane-Car-Boat/291584105459?epid=2147121990&hash=item43e3c45bf3:g:vT8AAOSwXshWqIW~). However, i recently heard someone describe an encoded dc motor, like this one:[image] 
Is this in fact a proper servo? does the term "servo" just mean ANY motor that had a feedback system? (i think "closed loop" is the term)

Comment: A motor with some form of negative feedback (a 'closed loop') is a servomechanism. e.g. position feedback from a potentiometer, velocity feedback from a tacho-generator, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Servo means that there is negative feedback for the controller. So motor and encoder are required, but to be servo they need proper controllers, that uses encoder to control the motor.

Comment: what is negative feedback?

Comment: That means you take your position command, subtract the feedback from it (negative- means you subtract) and get the error. So by the error you decide how to adjust the motor. But you should better google control theory, there is much more to it.

Comment: @parzival, to put it another way, negative feedback here means that the drive to the motor is derived from the difference between (a) where the motor is supposed to be and (b) where it currently is.

Answer (score 2):

Servo = a whole system which keeps some quantity controlled. If the controlled system output is linear mechanical placement or rotation angle, the motor can well be a servomotor. Some of us may extend this to the cases where speed, revolution speed, force or torque are controlled. I am not one of them. When I read or hear the combined word servomotor, I expect the motor is ready to use (=has the controllability and the needed sensors) in linear placement or rotation angle control system as the part which does the mechanical work.

The optical encoder, which obviously output the current rotation angle, does not make a motor a servomotor if the rotation angle is not controllable. The encoded output can be used by a third party who must know the current angle without any attempt to stop the rotation at a wanted position. For example simple DC motors cannot be forced effectively to stop at a certain position. A high ratio gearpack is a must for precision control.

If your motor happens to be controllable (has a hidden gearpack) as a servomotor, it still isn't a servo until also the controller circuits and a method to input the wanted rotation angle are included.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, if it can go to a position and actively hold it.

This kind of rules out DC motors because they cannot activate the magnets for the current position, but the type of encoder used is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: It certainly doesn't rule out DC motors. Also, servos are not restricted to position/displacement control.